# Branding in a Solution file instead of deployed site

Tags: 2010, solution-package, branding

I have experience branding sites through SharePoint designer. I am now shifting gears from working in SharePoint Designer on .aspx pages with javascript/HTML/CSS to working in Visual Studio with C# on Solution files.

I am trying to better understand how to structure HTML and CSS using ASP.NET. For example in the past if I wanted to brand a list view I would simply modify the html and styles of a rendered list view web part in SharePoint Designer. Now I have to brand it **before** it ever deploys. It is this concept that is making my head hurt.

Can anyone explain how this works, say for example in a list view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKS has a branding template for SharePoint. Apart from it, we can structure our project solution and categorize the elements say masterpages, pagelayouts, Scripts, Styles, Images, Webparts, List Definitions and similar way create features to deploy independently.

- master pages, page layout, styles, scripts, images - Feature 1 (Web\Site - scoped)
- Webparts - Feature 2 (Site - scope)
- List Definition - Feature 3 (Web\Site - scoped)

To the specific question i.e. styling a list view web part, you can create a visual web part and use the list view web part in it and customize the web part to your needs. As Visual Web part gives you an option to style the web part using .ascx file

Hope this helps you!!!